# Cannot call window.parent from IE7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, popupwindow, modalpopups

I am trying to make a simple call to my parent class from a modal-popup but IE is fighting me all the way.  Any suggestions to get around it would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the stripped down code that I'm trying to use.  It works quite well in FireFox but throws an error in IE - "Object doesn't support this property or method", referencing the line of code in the "Catch" block.  This means that both the line in the Try and the Catch block do not work.

parent.html

```
<html><head>
<script>
function callMain(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}

function modalWin() {
    if (window.showModalDialog) {
        window.showModalDialog("topFrame1.html","name",
        "dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px");
    } else {
        window.open('topFrame1.html','name',
        'toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,modal=yes');
    }
}

function getMainFrameVal()
{
    return document.getElementById("mainframe").value;
}

</script>
</head> <body>
<a href="#" onclick="modalWin()" >PopUpWindow</a>
<form>
<input type=text id="mainframe" value="main"/>
</body></html>
```

topFrame1.html

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getMain(){
try{
    alert("1 "+ window.opener.getMainFrameVal());
}catch(e)
{
    alert("2 " +window.parent.getMainFrameVal());
}
}
</script>
</head> <body>
TOP <a href="#" onclick="getMain()">click for main</a> <br/><br/>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if you found one helpful- or make comments if you'd like clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`window.opener` is for use with opening popups with `window.open()`.

Are you sure parent.html is the parent of topFrame1.html and you're not secretly using a frameset or something?

Answer (score 0):

The IE modal dialog is not a really a true window, and does not support window.opener.  To reference the parent window, you would have to pass the window reference in as part of the dialog arguments like this:

```
    window.showModalDialog("topFrame1.html",["name", window],
    "dialogWidth:255px;dialogHeight:250px");
```

Then you can reference the parent in the child with this line:

```
    alert("1 "+ window.dialogArguments[1].getMainFrameVal());
```

My advice though is to stay away from IE dialogs altogether and just use one solution that works in all browsers, such as `window.open()` or [jQuery dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).